# What exactly was Worf's job in TNG Season 1?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I'm pretty sure the Token Klingon was not a Starfleet position.

However, he doesn't really seem to have a specific job to do.   What were the writers thinking at the time?

Obviously in season two, when Worf moves to Tactical and Security Chief (and Geordi moves to  Chief Engineer) it all seems to make sense, but maybe this is hindsight.

Comment: To get smacked around in order to show how powerful the villain of the week was.

Comment: It was to "learn, learn, learn" ("Lonely Among Us").

Answer (score 8):

In the first season Worf was primarily a relief bridge officer.

> In 2364, Lieutenant junior grade Worf was assigned as a command division bridge officer on the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D), under the command of Captain Jean-Luc Picard. Worf spent most of his first year on the Enterprise-D as a relief officer for the conn and other bridge stations.
>
> Following the death of Natasha Yar at the hands of the Armus entity, Worf became acting security chief. In 2365, Worf transferred to the operations division and officially became the Enterprise-D's chief tactical officer and security chief. He was promoted to the rank of full lieutenant in 2366. After seven years of service aboard the starship, Worf rose in rank to lieutenant commander in 2371.

Here are more [Worf stats](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf).

Comment: OK, but anything on the state of thinking on the part of the writers?

Comment: Additional evidence from TNG Writers/Director Guide (http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/2_The_Next_Generation/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_Bible.pdf)  page 15 indicates:   Bridge AFT STATIONS: Normally monitored by only one officer, WORF, who operates different consoles as needed.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Great citation, that seems to confirm that his position was originally conceived exactly as described on the wiki.